# Implenting an SSL certificate for DynDns

Tags: domains, dns, security-certificate, dynamic-dns

I need help in implementing an SSL Certificate. We have a DynDns host which is linked to our Dynamic Public IP. We want to implement an SSL certificate from a Public CA for our DynDns address.

Do I have to purchase another domain and create a CNAME record pointing to the DynDns address. Would this work? What would the user put in their browser?

Comment: We have a paid account with dyndns, where we have around 15 hosts which  are linked to all branch offices. vpn are configured. we have an internal server which we will access from WAN by putting our dyndns address & it shows certificate warning.to get rid of that warning we need to implement a ssl certificate. we dont want any change in our current config,. we just need to implement ssl certificate. i frnd told me that if i will purchase a domain and create a CNAME record that will point to my abc.dyndns.org address.then we can get ssl certificate for our domain. is this right way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SSL Certifications with Standard DNS since its associated with the server and common name. You can not use a purchased SSL certification on the free service as its not supported, however you can use a self signed cert. Your find all this information on  [DynDNS SSL](http://www.dyndns.com/support/kb/sslcert.html) cert page.

> [**SOURCE**](http://www.dyndns.com/support/kb/sslcert.html#faqs-dynamic)
>
> Do SSL Certificates work with dynamic IP addresses?
>
> Yes. SSL Certificates are associated with the server and Common Name,
> not the IP address, so you may use SSL Certificates with our Dyn
> [Standard DNS service](http://dyn.com/standard-dns/) and a dynamic IP address without a problem.
>
> [**SOURCE**](http://www.dyndns.com/support/kb/sslcert.html#faqs-ddns)
>
> Third-party SSL certificates cannot be used with our free Dynamic DNS
> hosts, including the certificates we offer. You may use self-signed
> certificates for Dynamic DNS hosts. If you need the security of our
> certificates for business transactions or corporate use, you may wish
> to [create your own domain registration and DNS service](https://account.dyn.com/services/zones/svc/add.html?_add_dns=c&_add_dmn=r) and purchase
> SSL certificates for your new domain.